# Separable equation $y'=y+x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation which I'm having a hard time to solve.

$y'=y+x$

I have to decide the linear function $y=ax+b$, which is the solution to the differential equation. Any help is grately appreciated.

Comment: substitute it ${{}}$

Comment: It is not separable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already know some linear function $\,y=ax+b\,$ *must* be the (a) solution, do what Ilya proposes: substitute.

$$y=ax+b\Longrightarrow a=y'=y+x=(a+1)x+b\Longrightarrow a= (a+1)x+b\Longleftrightarrow a=-1\, a= b= -1$$

comparing degrees in both sides, so your solution is $\,y=-x-1\,$

Answer (score 4):

Introduce new function $u(x)=y(x)+x.$ Then $y(x)=u(x)-x$ and $y'(x)=u'(x)-1.$ Substitution into equation yields
$$u'(x)-1=u(x)$$ or
$$u'(x)=u(x)+1, \\
\dfrac{u'(x)}{u(x)+1}=1, \\
\dfrac{\dfrac{d}{dx}(u(x)+1)}{u(x)+1}=1, \\
\dfrac{d}{dx}(\ln(u(x)+1))=1.
$$
Now you can simply integrate it.

Comment: Of course allowing for the solution here $u(x)+1=0$, namely $y=-x-1$ (the linear solution the OP sought).

Comment: @Steve D Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the answer also as follows. Let $y'-y=x$ is our OE. this is a first linear ODE and can be solve by setting a proper integrating factor $\mu(x)=\text{e}^{\int p(x)dx}$ where $p(x)$ is the coefficient of $y$ when the coefficient of $y'$ be $1$. Now you have : $$\mu(x)=\exp(\int(-1)dx)=\exp(-x)$$ Multiply this to your OE: $$\exp(-x)y'-\exp(-x)y=x\exp(-x)$$ Or $$d\left(\exp(-x)y\right)=x\exp(-x)$$. Integrate from both sides of the last identity.

Comment: +1 Nice and straightforward, though in this case it may be an overkill as the OP says he wants to show some particular function is the solution...

Comment: @DonAntonio 1 i hope that he knows definition of derivative,because in this case it is simplest,if he knows  that $y=a*x+b$  this is  form of solution,then he can directly put it into equation

Comment: Honestly, mine is like an overdose for that poor OE. :D

Comment: :D,i think so too

Comment: Nice and straightforward! +1

Answer (score 2):

This is a linear DE of 1st order.

write dy/dx-y=x

IF = e^(integral -xdx) = e^(-x)

Multiply both sides of the DE with the IF to get:
d[(e^-x)(y)]/dx = xe^(-x)

Integrate both sides to get:
(e^-x)(y) = Integral xe^(-x)dx
Use ILATE to solve integral on right hand side by taking x as 1 st function and integrating by parts to get:

(e^-x)(y) = (e^-x)(-x) - (e^-x)
Cancel e^-x on both sides to get:

y = -x-1

Regards,
Prakash Mudholkar

Answer (score 1):

generally   you can represent  you equation as

$dy/dx-y(x)=x$

which is called first-order linear ordinary differential equation,because i  can't use Latex for formating math,there is link for solution of this  kind of problem
http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/lineareq/lineareq.html

by the way  if  purpose is to find linear  form.then general form of linear form is

$y=a*x+b$

Comment: I agree with you,dato.

Answer (score 1):

$ y'=y+x  $ $\implies$ $y'-y=x$

Multiplies both side by $e^{-x}$

$(y'-y)e^{-x}=xe^{-x}$

Note that $(y'-y)e^{-x}=(ye^{-x})'$

Therefore

$(ye^{-x})'=xe^{-x}$ $\implies$ $(ye^{-x})=\int xe^{-x}dx+C$ $\implies$$y(x)=e^{x}\int xe^{-x}dx+Ce^x $

Can you calculate $\int e^{-x}xdx$

Comment: maybe he does not need  such  solution,only linear form